# Customizing pagination with Datatables

Tags: jquery, css, pagination, datatables

I used Datatables and I want to customize the pagination to the color I want to match the theme of my page.

[image]

This is the default view.

I have tried different methods, like using the same class done in datatables and use `!important`. It worked but did not show what I intended to do.

What I want when active and also when in `:hover` state:

- background-color: black;
- color: white;

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

put below css in your style

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current:hover{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1) !important;
    color:#fff !important;
}
```

Comment: check if you have added color property with  !important somewhere else. if you are using firefox and firebug then you can inspect the element and check in computed tab, which class is actually responsible for the color.

Comment: yes i added !important. however I saw in the datatable.css file. it has color: black !important.

Comment: you can use the same class structure as datatable.css to override it

Comment: still doesn't work. But thanks anyways! You're a huge help.